# How to configure UFW to allow ntp to work?

Tags: firewall, ufw, ntp

I've enabled **UFW** on one of production servers with configuration: **Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing)**. For NTP synchronization, I've installed `ntp` and it's currently running.

Can someone advise what rule should be added to **UFW** for NTP synchronization? I've read somewhere that `udp port 123` needs to be open for **ntp**, but when I run `ntpq -p`, I get following output:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 propjet.latt.ne 187.253.153.32   2 u   4d 1024    0   81.243    9.054   0.000
 ec2-107-20-168- 130.207.244.240  2 u   4d 1024    0   86.669  -23.040   0.000
 utcnist2.colora .ACTS.           1 u   4d 1024    0  298.151   86.936   0.000
```

which indicates that I don't need to add any ufw rule and ntp is already working?

Comment: Why deny outgoing?

Comment: Just for extra security.
Actually I've another server which was comprised with some trojan(s) and we controlled it by denying outgoing for the time being.

Comment: Deny outgoing is no extra security. Clean your infected system. That's extra security.

Comment: I was talking  about two  different servers!
Extra security was meant for non-compromised server.

Comment: Maybe read the NTP FAQ to learn what `reach 0` actually means: You are not receiving NTP packets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following rules-set, NTP-synchronization is working perfectly for me:

```
sudo ufw allow 123/udp
sudo ufw allow out 123/udp
sudo ufw allow out 53
```

I've allowed **UDP** port **123** for both incoming and outgoing traffic to NTP work. Additionally I also needed to open **TCP** port **53** (DNS) for outgoing traffic since `/etc/ntp.conf` contains domain names of NTP servers. .

Answer (score 15):

With a simple

```
sudo ufw allow ntp
```

---

You can use all services listed in `/etc/services`

```
sudo ufw allow <service name>
```

Comment: Thanks!
But as I mentioned in my post without allowing **ntp** , I am still getting proper response of `ntpq -p`, what might be the reason?

Comment: Allowing **ntp** for incoming traffic is not enough in my case.  As I mentioned in the question, default outgoing traffic is blocked, so I've allowed UDP 123 for both incoming and outgoing traffic to ntp work.

Comment: Read your own comment "and we controlled it by denying outgoing for the time being."

Comment: I was talking about two different servers.  Please have a look at my question and comments again. Thanks

Comment: You can also use `getent service` or `getent service ntp` to see which ports are used by `NTP` by default.  It uses same mechanism that C programs uses.